# Pass Member Function to Variadic Template Function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have a class with a function called enqueue:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
inline auto ThreadPool::enqueue(T && t, Args&&... args) ->std::future<typename std::result_of<T(Args ...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()>> (
       std::bind(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    );

    std::future<return_type> result = task->get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        // Don't allow job creation after stopping pool.
        if (m_done)
            throw std::runtime_error("Enqueue on stopped ThreadPool.");

        m_tasks.emplace([task]() { (*task)(); });
    }

    m_cond.notify_one();
    m_futures.push_back(move(result));
    return result;
}
```

This is an inline implementation done inside of the header file alongside the ThreadPool class.

It is a singleton and should be able to take any function with its arguments, add this to a task queue and return a future of the result type of that function.

Here is the class where I am trying to use it:

```
void Grepper::scan(std::tr2::sys::path const& folder, std::string expression, bool verbose) {
    // Create directory iterators.
    std::tr2::sys::recursive_directory_iterator d(folder);
    std::tr2::sys::recursive_directory_iterator e;

    // Create tasks from files that match initial extension list.
    for (; d != e; ++d) {
        if (!std::tr2::sys::is_directory(d->status()) && std::find(m_extensions.begin(), m_extensions.end(), d->path().extension().generic_string()) != m_extensions.end()) {
            ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue(grep, d->path(), expression, verbose);
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives a compiler error of:

```
Error C3867 'Grepper::grep': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I have tried creating a functor to this function as well as passing the function as a lambda:

```
ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue([this](std::tr2::sys::path p, std::string s, bool b) { grep(p, s, b); });
```

Which gives me the following compiler error:

```
Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
```

For reference here is the declaration of my grep method:

```
void grep(std::tr2::sys::path file, std::string expression, bool verbose);
```

How do I pass this function and its arguments properly to the enqueue method?

Comment: Using `bind` is just wrong when you are computing `result_of` directly.

Comment: @T.C. Could that be the reason why it is not allowing me to pass member functions?

Comment: *"I have tried creating a functor to this function as well as passing the function as a lambda:"*, you probably meant to use `ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue([this](std::tr2::sys::path p, std::string s, bool b) { grep(p, s, b); }, d->path(), expression, verbose);`, or `ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue([this,d,expression, verbose] { grep(d->path(), expression, verbose); });`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Dude, awesome! I didn't know you had to pass parameters to the lambda in order for it to pass em along to the function itself. Makes sense now that I see it. If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll gladly mark it correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attempt with a pointer to a member function fails for two reasons:

1. To form a pointer to a member function, you need to use `&Grepper::grep` syntax.
2. A member function requires an implicit object parameter (among other arguments, so that it can be also properly handled by `std::bind` and `std::result_of`).

Having said that, you could try the following call:

```
ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue(
   &Grepper::grep
   , this
   , d->path()
   , expression
   , verbose
);
```

The attempt with a lambda expression fails, because that lambda expression passed as an argument:

```
[this] (std::tr2::sys::path p, std::string s, bool b) { grep(p, s, b); }
```

declares three parameters, so the `Args` parameter pack must not be empty. But *it is* in your case:

```
ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue(
    [this] (std::tr2::sys::path p, std::string s, bool b) { grep(p, s, b); }        
);
```

Those arguments, according to your design, should be either passed in a call to `enqueue`:

```
ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue(
    [this] (std::tr2::sys::path p, std::string s, bool b) { grep(p, s, b); }
    , d->path()
    , expression
    , verbose
);
```

or captured by a lambda expression, so that no additional `Args` are needed:

```
ThreadPool::get_instance().enqueue(
    [this,d,expression,verbose] { grep(d->path(), expression, verbose); }
);
```