# Trying to pass a function from a class to a variadic template function

Tags: c++, class, parameters, formatting, variadic-templates

So I have a group project that is comparing the sort times of various sorting functions. I am trying to cut down the amount of copy/pasting code by using a variadic template function. I have read everything I can find on google about them and how to pass functions as parameters. It has been literally DAYS of working on this, and I can't seem to make this work. I've been able to pass a function that is defined in my main cpp file outside of a class, but I can't make it work for the functions that belong to a class.

My group has asked me to abandon this idea (we are running out of time), but I feel like I am so close to getting it. If anyone can help out with the syntax, I would be so grateful. I also tried using the function type from the functional library, which was the only way that semi-worked. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444747/pass-member-function-to-variadic-template-function) question on stack overflow and the guy had the same error I was getting about using '&', but I still can't seem to make this work.

*edit*
As per the comments, I tried to make the code as basic and concise as possible. :)
I spent more time than I should have trying to find the function that I had gotten to work, but I did not save a copy of it. I read that I should include code that allows others to duplicate the error, but I have not been able to re-create it. The best I can do is a hypothetical example at this point.
Lets say I have a function in a class called Sorts:

```
    void Sorts::InsertionSort(vector<int> &v_small, int length)
    {
       //does the thing that sorts the stuff
       cout << "display the sorted stuff" << endl
    }
```

and a vector in a class called Data:

```
    class Data{
    public
        vector<int> dataSmall;
    };
```

both of these are in a separate header file. For simplicity, lets call it "header." :)

```
run_timer(InsertionSort, vector_to_sort, size_of_vector);
```

I also have a function, in my cpp file, that (is attempting) to take a function parameter, a vector parameter, and a size parameter.

```
    template <class Ret, class... Args> class function<Ret(Args...)>
    run_timer3(function<void(Args...)> sort_func(int), vector<int>& array, int size...)
    {
        //start the timer

        //call function to time, sort_func sometimes has 3 parameters though
        sort_func(array, size);

        //stop the timer

        //calculate and write to file
    }
```

I know I should be able to figure this out with generic examples but I'll just be honest it does not compute. All I need is to know how to pass a function that exists in a class. Although now that I lost the function that was working, maybe I need some help making the function definition as well. :(

[This](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/) was probably the most helpful page I had found on variadic templates.

Sorry if this is to similar to the one I linked before, but I really can't understand what it is I'm doing wrong. I really don't want to have to have the same block of code with different variables 162 times. If anyone can offer guidance I will send you cyber feet-kisses. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to paste in all that code. A question should contain a [mcve]. Note the **minimal**.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you would edit your post and provide just the required code, this would increase the chance to get a helpful answer. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance on how to make your question a good question.

Comment: Yeah after I posted I saw that link about not posting a ton of code. Sorry! I've done a bit of editing, to make the most important bits more accessible. Should I still delete all of the other code? I just included it for context (like if I'm using the wrong namespace or not including a header or something).

Comment: Side note: `function<void(vector<int> &array, int size)>` you don't need to name the variables in the template arguments.

Comment: @Azlynne I dare to suggest to remove _all_ code which is not _absolutely_ neccessary to understand and reproduce your problem. Focus on the problem! Context is usually irrelevant and makes it more difficult to reuse question and helpful answer for people having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question contains way more code then I feel like sifting through, I'll just give you an example on how to pass a function to a template.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    f();
}

struct bar {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }
    void baz() {
        foo([&]() { print(); });
    }
};

void print() {
    std::cout << "free\n";
}

int main () {
    foo(print);
    bar b;

    b.baz();
    foo([&]() { b.print(); });
}
```

A free function can simply be passed in. If you want to pass a member-function you can wrap it in a lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found examples like this while researching. I really have spent time looking ...So there's no way to do what I want to do w/out a lambda? I've heard the word before, but don't know what it is. I googled it, but unfortunately I don't have time to teach myself yet another thing (already did that with the current problem). I will absolutely do so in the near future, I just can't right now as the project is due very soon.

I did update the question to make it more concise, if you're willing to take another look. Not sure if you'd be willing to be more specific?